# Fastest way to traverse DOM (Breadth First)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

Sorry if this will sound like a strange need.

Users can create a HTML page with any number of  elements in any order, Div's will be assigned a class. I have no control over which order or where they are placed.

I need to traverse the DOM and call an init function on each div with the class names specific to my framework. So I do not know the order they will be placed.

Here are my challenges:
- I am using a recursive .children() Jquery call then iterating through each child of the current element... I think I need to find a faster way of doing this, it is a performance hit.
- When iterating, $.each() is faster than a standard for loop. I have no idea why. Does $.each() perform faster for smaller sets? (i.e. size < 20 )

My other alternative is to do a selector on each class but I need to do several iterations as this can't guarantee the ordering so the iterations cancel out any performance advantage.

So My needs:
- A better performing way to traverse the DOM breadth first. Plain ol' Javascript is fine if I can find better performance than JQuery functions.

Sorry, I know this sounds a bit of a strange need. Any advice is greatly welcome.

Comment: No, `$.each` is never faster than a for-loop. Show us some code!

Comment: _"Does $.each() perform faster for smaller sets? (i.e. size < 20 )"_ - No. It shouldn't be faster at all unless your plain `for` loop had other issues, for example if it was reselecting elements on each iteration where your `$.each()` loop didn't. Please show your code.

Comment: I guess a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/TreeWalker) or a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeIterator) should be quite boosted for DOM traversal

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be having a huge performance hit. The issue could somewhere else in your code, but you haven't shown us what you currently have, so I have no way of saying. That said, here's an idea that should be pretty speedy:

```
var classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"];
i = classes.length, divs, j, curDiv;

while(i--) {
    divs = document.getElementsByClassName(classes[i]);
    j = divs.length;

    while(j--) {
        var curDiv = divs[j];
        // call some init function on the current div
    } 
}
```

If this isn't fast, you must have an issue somewhere else (also, don't forget to make sure this is called after the document has loaded).

---

As for whether `$.each()` is faster than a standard `for` loop, this is pretty much a rule of thumb: native code is faster than library code (but library code is usually more convenient). That holds true in this case; your average `for` loop will be much faster than `$.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something a little bit more concise, with some current syntax.

```js
    function bfs(root) {
      const queue = [];
      while (root) {
        console.log(root);
        [...root.children].forEach(child => queue.push(child));
        root = queue.shift();
      }
    }

    bfs(document.body);
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Breadth First</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="a">
          <div class="aa">
            <span class="aaa"></span>
            <span class="aab"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ab">
          <span class="aba"></span>
          <span class="abb"></span>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For breadth first tree traversal...

```
const html = `<div class="a">
    <div class="aa">
        <span class="aaa">
        </span>
        <span class="aab">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="ab">
        <span class="aba">
        </span>
        <span class="abb">
        </span>
    </div
</div>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

function BFT_dom(root) {

    const queue = [];
    let currentEl = root;

    while(currentEl) {
      console.log(currentEl) // Do something to element here

      for(let i = 0; i < currentEl.children.length; i++) {
          queue.push(currentEl.children[i]);
      }
      currentEl = queue.shift();
  }

}

BFT_dom(doc)
```